# How to set Low asterisk

Tags: subscripts

Hi I am using Guliver font, in this font asterisk symbol comes in default superscript postion, but I want lower asterisk. Please suggest me how to fix this.

Comment: You could always use a `\raisebox` with a negative length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a command for that. I found it using [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Test * vs \textasteriskcentered
\end{document}
```

[image]